# Active Directory or Mac configuration. Where to look?

Tags: active-directory, ssh, mac-osx, ldap, user-management

I m a student at a university.

There is a computer lab which has Mac computers.

There is citrix account which is kinda VPN to school network. There is putty in citrix applications.

When i use putty and try to ssh into a Mac, my access is denied. However an sysadmin of the school is able to login to mac using putty and school credentials.

Well, where to look to fix this problem ?

Is this the Active Directory configuration for students or this is due to Mac configuration?

and how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clean this question up? Maybe have the sysadmin look at your question and ask them to clean it up?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, I think the answer is "ask the school sysadmin."

Comment: School admin said that He doesnt know about and i was asked to research this.

Answer (score 1):

1) It could be the computer or location you're trying to connect *from*. Test your account at the SysAdmin's computer (or have him test from yours).

2) If the sysadmin can use his school credentials to connect, but yours don't work (assuming they are also 'school credentials') then perhaps you could temporarily give yourself (or get him to give you) the same access as the admin and attempt the connection.  This should help determine if it's a permissions issue.